# CRUD Update not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, c#, crud

I am not able to figure out my update function. I am able to retrieve and delete from my database, but I don't understand how to update. This is all new to me so I am stumped.

.js file

```
//update user
$("#btnUpdateUser").click(function () {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'PUT',
            url: uri,
            data: JSON.stringify(vendor),
            processdata: true,



    public int updateUser(vendors vendors, int id)
    {


            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE vendors set  [user]=@user, email=@email, phoneNumber=@phoneNumber, business=@business, comments=@comments where id=@Id", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", vendors.user);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", vendors.email);
```

I was getting a "Record not found" before, but I am not longer getting that. 
Any guidance/hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you want to be updating the id field?

Comment: are you using entity framework or something similar?

Comment: Also, please tell us what database back-end you are using.

Comment: I am using sql database.

Comment: I wasn't sure about the id field honestly.I started off without the id field.

Comment: @user3353920 Are you using MS SQL Server? MySQL? Postgres? etc?

Comment: Yes I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

Best thing to do is go into debugger mode and add a break point at the start of the `updateUser` method in the file vender.cs in visual studio.

Check all the variables are expected by hovering your mouse over `venders` and `id` (I am suspecting you are missing to include the ID in your url call?)

Another point to check - I noticed that you are trying to update the ID, which is not good practice. - remove that

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have removed the update of my id. I will debug and see what I get.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the URI is missing the id or having a wrong id ( during the fetching of records )

Answer (score 0):

```
            /////////////////////////////////// sekili sil x gore //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
let deleteButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".My-Delete-Btn");

deleteButtons.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function () {
    btn.parentElement.remove();

}));



////////////////////////////////////////// silmek ucun sorus //////////////////////////////////////////
let itemdelete = document.querySelectorAll(".item-delete");

itemdelete.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Are you sure?',
        text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
        icon: 'warning',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
        confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then((result) => {
        if (result.isConfirmed) {
            let url = btn.getAttribute("href");

            fetch(url)
                .then(response => {
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        window.location.reload(true);
                    } else {
                        alert("errorrr");
                    }
                })
        }
    })

}))

///////////////////////////////////////// add to basket ///////////////////////////////////////////////

let addtobasket = document.querySelectorAll(".add-to-basket");


addtobasket.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener("click", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    let url = btn.getAttribute("href");

    fetch(url)
        .then(response =>
        {
            if (response.status == 200)
                alert("added basket");
            else 
                alert("error");
            
        }
    )

}))/////////////////////////////// book controllere elave edilmeli olan checkout ucun ///////////////////////////////////

        public IActionResult AddItemToBasket(int BookId)
        {

            if (!_myDb.books.Any(x => x.Id == BookId)) return NotFound();

            List<BasketItemViewModel> basketItems = new List<BasketItemViewModel>();
            BasketItemViewModel basketVm = null;

            string basketitemsStr = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BasketItems"];

            if (basketitemsStr != null)
            {
                basketItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BasketItemViewModel>>(basketitemsStr);

                basketVm = basketItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == BookId);

                if (basketVm != null) { basketVm.count++; }
                else
                {
                    basketVm = new BasketItemViewModel
                    {
                        Id = BookId,
                        count = 1
                    };
                    basketItems.Add(basketVm);
                }

            }
            else
            {
                basketVm = new BasketItemViewModel
                {
                    Id = BookId,
                    count = 1
                };

                basketItems.Add(basketVm);
            }


            basketitemsStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(basketItems);

            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("BasketItems", basketitemsStr);

            return Ok();

        }

        public IActionResult GetBasket()
        {
            List<BasketItemViewModel> basketItems = new List<BasketItemViewModel>();

            string basketItemStr = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BasketItems"];
            if (basketItemStr != null)
            {
                basketItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BasketItemViewModel>>(basketItemStr);
            }

            return Json(basketItems);
        }

        public IActionResult Checkout()
        {
            List<CheckoutItemViewModel> checkouts = new List<CheckoutItemViewModel>();
            List<BasketItemViewModel> basketitems = new List<BasketItemViewModel>();
            CheckoutItemViewModel checkoutItem= null;

            string basketitemsStr = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BasketItems"];

            if(basketitemsStr != null)
            {
                basketitems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<BasketItemViewModel>>(basketitemsStr);
            }

            foreach (var item in basketitems)
            {
                checkoutItem = new CheckoutItemViewModel
                {
                    book = _myDb.books.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == item.Id),
                    count = item.count
                };
                checkouts.Add(checkoutItem);
            }



            return View(checkouts);
        }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).